# Get element id on hover (or mouseover)

Tags: jquery

Still getting to grips with jQuery and I am pleased to have got as far as I have, especially help from the posts in this forum. However, now got to a working function that does what I want, that is to create a radio group that looks like a button. It pulls data via json and loops through creating the radio buttons.

I want to get the id of the radio buttons generated so that I can then parse through to the next step of the app but I can't get it to work.

```
function FillDiv(groups, side) {
    var cnt = 1;
    var newClass = '';
    var newType = '';
    if (side == '#ck-button-left') {
        newClass = 'leftClass';
        newType = 'radio'
    }
    else {
        newClass = 'rightClass';
        newType = 'checkbox'
    }

    $.each(groups, function (index, groups) {
        $(side)
        .append(
            $(document.createElement('label')).attr({
                id: cnt + 'lbl'
            })
        );
        $('#' + cnt + 'lbl')
        .append(
            $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                id: groups.GroupCode,
                type: newType,
                name: 'testGroup',
                class: newClass
            })
        );
        $('#' + groups.GroupCode).after
        (
            $(document.createElement('span')).text(groups.GroupName).attr('class', 'leftSpan')
        );
        $('#' + cnt + 'lbl').after($(document.createElement('br')));
        cnt = cnt + 1;
    });
}
```

Looking through various searched, it should work with something like...

```
$('#leftSpan').mouseover(function () {
        $('#lblOutput').html(this.id);
});
```

or, as I suspect, it is something to do with the nesting of the label/input that I need to reference the parent or child.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `$(document.createElement('span'))` - why? Just use `$('<span/>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This led to further questions in a follow up post "An issue I have not resolved related to my 'Get element id on hover (or mouseover)'". Solution is found at [An issue I have not resolved related to my 'Get element id on hover (or mouseover)' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923631/an-issue-i-have-not-resolved-related-to-my-get-element-id-on-hover-or-mouseove)

Comment: Please add the *actual* answer to this question as an answer, and not just a link to another question that answers it indirectly, or at least don't mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you are using an `id` selector for selecting a `class`, try this:

```
$('.leftSpan').mouseover(function () {
        $('#lblOutput').text(this.id);
});
```

Comment: This led to further questions in a follow up post "An issue I have not resolved related to my 'Get element id on hover (or mouseover)'". Solution is in there.