# An issue I have not resolved related to my 'Get element id on hover (or mouseover)' post

Tags: jquery

Basically this is my function:

```
function FillDivLeft(groups, side) {
 var cnt = 1;
 $.each(groups, function (index, groups) {
     $(side)
     .append(
         $(document.createElement('label')).attr({
             id: cnt + 'lbl',
             class: 'myClass'
         })
     );
     $('#' + cnt + 'lbl')
     .append(
         $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
             id: groups.GroupCode,
             type: 'checkbox',
             name: 'testGroup',
             class: 'leftClass'
         })
     );
     $('#' + groups.GroupCode).after
     (
         $(document.createElement('span')).text(groups.GroupName).attr({
             class: 'leftSpan'
         })
     );
     $('#' + cnt + 'lbl').after($(document.createElement('br')));
     cnt = cnt + 1;
 }); 
}
```

I have tried all sorts and although the new elements are created, classes assigned etc. it appears that all jquery functions on the page do not work, such as:

```
$('.leftSpan').click(function () {
    $('#lblOutput').text(this.id);
});
```

Even a hover function on the parent div does not work.

I can't see a possible cause so any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'on' if you are using jQuery 1.7+.  You can replace 'body' with any parent div of the element

```
$('body').on('click','.leftSpan',(function () {
    $('#lblOutput').text(this.id);
});
```

Using just the .click function requires the elements to be created when the dom is ready.  It will not attach the event to elements created dynamically.  If you are using jQuery 1.6 and below you will have to use the .live instead

You can read more about 'on' here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have just tried this but it shows an error as the is a missing closing bracket. Can you please advise where it should be. I tried it at the end, but that then breaks the jquery.

Comment: can you go to jsfiddle.net and paste your relevant code there?

Comment: The data used for the buttons is from a json response, can I do that in jfiddle? I've not used it before I must admit.

Comment: You should be able to look at the developer console and it will tell you what line and where the error is then.

Comment: OK, the cause of most of the error was that I had stupidly not read the bit about .on being js 1.7 on and I have 1.6.1

Anyway, with a tweak to  I got the id as follows:

    [code]$('.myClass .leftClass').live('click', function () {  
        $('#lblOutput').text(this.id);
    });

Comment: If I change 'click' to 'hover' or 'mouseover' however it does not work. @wirey, Any idea on that one?

Comment: If you put up a fiddle with the hover code I can probably figure out what the problem is

Comment: I've put up the code snippet and used the html generated as seen in chromes dev window.http://jsfiddle.net/petercor/RQ4Yp/3/

Comment: sorry, I put in the wrong snippet, but it should be ok now. http://jsfiddle.net/petercor/RQ4Yp/6/

Comment: It's because you are checking for over over an input that's not there.  You need to check for hover over the span.  Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4Yp/8/

Comment: I revised the fiddle to use the left side and it works in the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/petercor/RQ4Yp/9/ but let or right do not work in my code base so there is something close and I wonder if it is to do with the .on/.live? I have to get ready for a weeks vacation so I will have to leave this until I return otherwise my wife will go mad!!!

Comment: You can select both by separating them by commas in the selector $('.leftClass,.rightClass').next('span').hover(function() {  Here's an updated fiddle with the update http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4Yp/10/  And have fun on your vacation

Comment: Thanks @wirey for all your help. I found some time before going away to have another play and the following worked: `code`$('.myClass .leftSpan').live('hover' , function () {
                $('#lblOutput').text($(this).prev('input').prop('id'));
            });or using 1.7.2 I got this too: 
 `code` $(document).on('hover', '.myClass .leftSpan', function () {
        $('#lblOutput').text($(this).prev('input').prop('id'));
    });

Comment: :) I'm glad to help.  Have fun on your vacation and stop thinking about this already

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$(this)` instead of `this`? Or using `.attr('id')` instead of `.id`?

`$('.leftSpan').click(function () {
    $('#lblOutput').text($(this).attr('id'));
});`

Comment: The proper way to get the 'id' would be $('element').prop('id') or this.id works also.  'ID' is a property of the element

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all these but none are working, I think that's the problem nothing is.